# untar a file.tar.gz and directly creat a gz file (file_1.gz and file_2.gz) from the untar files with one command

Tags: gzip, tar, gunzip

I have a tar file that contains two files.

file.tar.gz

The file includes:

file_1.fastq

file_2.fastq

I want to untar the original file and directly gzip the untar files with one command and have the following files:

file_1.fastq.gz

file_2.fastq.gz

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Ehsan

Answer (score 0):

The command would be something like this, as a script:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
tar xzf ../file.tar.gz
gzip *
mv * ..
cd ..
rmdir temp
```